# Set separate threading policies for queues in the same Service bus for Azure Function Queue Trigger

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

So we just found out how we can set our Azure function that is listening to a service bus queue to run as Single Threaded which is great for the issue we were dealing with on one of our queues. However we have another queue in the same service bus where it is not hyper critical to process messages synchronously.

By editing our **host.json** we were able to set the **MaxConcurrentCalls** to 1 but obviously this now cascades down to both queue listener functions in the same project. Is there a way to separate these settings or would we have to have 2 separate function apps altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately today the host settings are shared for all functions in the app - so you would need to separate these two functions into two separate apps.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks!